# Passing by reference, $a = &$b, is $a=$n the same as $b=$n?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to understand passing by reference.  This is probably a bad analogy, but is it like Newton's 3rd law (action-reaction pairs)?

For example, for the following code

```
$a = 4;
$b = 2;
$n = 42;
$a = &$b;
```

is

`$a=$n` the same as `$b=$n`?  Isn't the value of `$a` and `$b` stored in the same address?

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php to read about it..

Comment: Pass a value explictly by reference is deprecated and can't be do with the actual PHP version. Only a method can define if the argument must be received by reference

Comment: @Maks3w no its not deprecated. Only using it in conjunction with `new` operator is deprecated. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php). `Since PHP 5, new returns a reference automatically, so using =& in this context is deprecated and produces an E_DEPRECATED message in PHP 5.3 and later, and an E_STRICT message in earlier versions`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you assign these variables normally:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;
```

Then the associations will look like this:

```
a --> 1
b --> 2
c --> 3
```

Now, if you make `$c` into a reference of `$a`, like this:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = &$a;
```

Then the associations will look like this:

```
a --> 1 <--.
b --> 2    |
c --------/
```

In other words, `$a` and `$c` point to the same value. Because they both point to the same value we can change either of the variables and they will both point to the new value.

```
$a = 5;
echo "$a $c"; // Output: "5 5"
$c = 10;
echo "$a $c"; // Output: "10 10"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, After assigning `$n` to `$a`, **`$b` will point `$n`**.

This is because **after executing `$a=&$b` both `$a` and `$b` references a same memory location and become reference variable (`is_ref=1`)**. And the reference count (`refcount`) of that specific memory location increases by `1`.  **Now whatever *value* you assign to any of those references both will point to same value.**

Executing `$a=$n`  means **value of `$n`** will be store to the location referenced by `$a`. And this is same location as `$b`.

See the example here.

`$a`, `$b`, `$n` are pointing different locations

```
php > $a = 4;
php > $b = 2;
php > xdebug_debug_zval('a'); // they are pointing different location
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=int(4)

php > xdebug_debug_zval('b'); // they are pointing different location
b: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=int(2)

php > $n = 42;
php > xdebug_debug_zval('n'); 
n: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=int(42)
```

$a and `$b` both  becomes a reference now

```
php > $a = &$b; 
php > xdebug_debug_zval('b');
b: (refcount=2, is_ref=1)=int(2)

php > xdebug_debug_zval('a'); // a too
a: (refcount=2, is_ref=1)=int(2)
```

Assigning new **value**, NOT references to    any of `$a` and `$b`

```
php > $a = $n;
php > xdebug_debug_zval('a'); // a holds $n's value '42' now
a: (refcount=2, is_ref=1)=int(42)


php > xdebug_debug_zval('b'); // same for b
b: (refcount=2, is_ref=1)=int(42)
```

Comment: Your text explination is wrong not correspond with your examples. "Executing $a=$n means value of $n will be store to the location referenced by $a. And this is same location as $b." and later "Assigning new value, NOT references to any of $a and $b"

Comment: "And this is same location as $b". $a has a new value in a new space of memory

Comment: @Maks3w so assigning new value means new space in memory? Where in my example I didn't show it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you create a variable `$a` and `$b`, each has a *unique memory address* where their data is stored.

However, if you tell the interpreter that `$a = &$b`, that means that $a and $b now have the *same memory address*. If you assign anything to $a, or to $b, they will both echo the same value, because they store data in the same place in memory.

If you want to experiment, I suggest starting up the PHP interactive interpreter from the command line:

```
php -a
php > $a = 1;
php > $b = 2;
php > echo $a . ' ' . $b;
1 2
php > $a = &$b;
php > echo $a . ' ' . $b;
2 2
php > $a = 1;
php > echo $a . ' ' . $b;
1 1
php > $b = 2;
php > echo $a . ' ' . $b;
2 2
```

Answer (score -1):

`$a = $b` & `$b = $n` has the same value but are different because the value is a primitive type and `primitive types pass by value`.

The most quick way to test if the code is using references or not is change the value of the source var and see if the target vars change his value or not.

```
$n = 1;
$a = $n;
$b = $n;

echo $a; // 1
echo $b; // 1
echo $n; // 1

$n = 2;

echo $a; // 1
echo $b; // 1
echo $n; // 2
```

---

However `objects always are passed by reference`

```
$n = new Object(1);
$a = $n;
$b = $n;

$n->newValue(5);

$a->printValue(); // 5
$b->printValue(); // 5

$a->newValue(7);

$b->printValue(); // 7
```

Comment: -1 Objects are not in the context here. Other part dont answer the question at all.